# Titanium Appcelerator ACS - (iPhone) Not able to receive Push Notifications which are sent successfully

Tags: ios, titanium, push-notification, appcelerator

For my titanium mobile application, I would like to integrate ACS Push Notifications. As a first step, I went through the Push Notifications doc. I've configured my settings for iOS as given in the doc. I've created two ACS users (lets say A & B) and subscribed them to my custom channel using the following code.

```
Cloud.PushNotifications.subscribe({
   channel: '4fa8c8bfb6855370430092d1',
   device_token: '0BCE1064500FBF6F122BB0000007D1B5F96BAC345FD0A950FD456098D36E0345'
}, function (e) {
     if (e.success) {
        alert('Success');
     } else {
       alert('Error:\n' +
        ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
    }
});
```

Now, under my ACS Push Notification settings, am able to see that i currently have 2 iOS clients subscribed to Push Notifications.
With the below piece of code, i've sent a broadcast message from Device A in which the ACS_UserA has logged in.

```
Cloud.PushNotifications.notify({
   channel: '4fa8c8bfb6855370430092d1',
   payload: 'Welcome to push notifications'
}, function (e) {
     if (e.success) {
        alert('Success');
     } else {
          alert('Error:\n' +
         ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
    }
});
```

I am getting the alert as 'Success'. But, am not able to receive the notification in another Device B in which the ACS_UserB has logged in.

According the documentation here, i should be receiving a Push message in the 'callback' callback. But it is never called.

```
Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications({
types: [
     Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE,
     Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT,
     Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SOUND
],
 success:function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('Device Token :  '+e.deviceToken);
},
 error:function(e) {
    Ti.API.warn("push notifications failed: "+e);
},
 callback:function(e) {
    alert ('Push received');
}
});
```

Titanium SDK version: 2.0.2 (04/18/12 12:18 0684d32) 
Titanium Studio, build: 2.0.1.201204132053 
iPhone Device family: iphone 
iPhone SDK version: 5.0
iPhone simulated device: iphone.

Need to crack this badly. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

is your application id: ***com.companyname.applicationname***? make sure you do not use ***com.companyname.**** instead!

Comment: I have resolved this issue. It was the certificate that was causing this.                                                            Delivery error: Invalid certificate chain (Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown)! I verified that the keystore i provided was produced according to specs...

I checked my iOS certificate and made sure it is correct.